# API Gateway throws an Internal Server Error

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, fastapi

login and signup API is sending good response in local(http://127.0.0.1:8000/login) but API Gateway throwing an exception. there are another APIs working fine, only issue with login and signup.

If removing the try-except block results in an internal server error

deployed fastAPI in API Gateway via aws lambda functions and applied CORS also

for reference login API

```
@route.post("/login", tags=['Account'])
def login(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    try:
        user = db.query(UserModel).filter_by(email=form_data.username).first()
        if user and verify_password(form_data.password, user.password):
            return {"access_token": signJWT(user), "token_type": "Bearer"}
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Incorrect username or password")
    except:
        db.rollback()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

In CloudWatch Logs I got this error
note: bcrypt is installed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/mangum/protocols/http.py", line 58, in run
    await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/var/task/fastapi/applications.py", line 276, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 83, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/var/task/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/var/task/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/var/task/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/var/task/fastapi/routing.py", line 165, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "/var/task/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "/var/task/anyio/to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "/var/task/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "/var/task/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "/var/task/routes/users.py", line 28, in login
    if user and verify_password(form_data.password, user.password):
  File "/var/task/crud.py", line 15, in verify_password
    return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)
  File "/var/task/passlib/context.py", line 2347, in verify
    return record.verify(secret, hash, **kwds)
  File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 792, in verify
    return consteq(self._calc_checksum(secret), chk)
  File "/var/task/passlib/handlers/bcrypt.py", line 591, in _calc_checksum
    self._stub_requires_backend()
  File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2254, in _stub_requires_backend
    cls.set_backend()
  File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2156, in set_backend
    return owner.set_backend(name, dryrun=dryrun)
  File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2176, in set_backend
    raise default_error
passlib.exc.MissingBackendError: bcrypt: no backends available -- recommend you install one (e.g. 'pip install bcrypt')
[ERROR] 2023-06-15T11:27:11.426Z bd791912-cd83-4274-b5dd-91c7280b9171 An error occurred running the application. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/task/mangum/protocols/http.py", line 58, in run await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send) File "/var/task/fastapi/applications.py", line 276, in __call__ await super().__call__(scope, receive, send) File "/var/task/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__ await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send) File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__ raise exc File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__ await self.app(scope, receive, _send) File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 83, in __call__ await self.app(scope, receive, send) File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__ raise exc File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__ await self.app(scope, receive, sender) File "/var/task/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__ raise e File "/var/task/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__ await self.app(scope, receive, send) File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__ await route.handle(scope, receive, send) File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle await self.app(scope, receive, send) File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app response = await func(request) File "/var/task/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app raw_response = await run_endpoint_function( File "/var/task/fastapi/routing.py", line 165, in run_endpoint_function return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values) File "/var/task/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args) File "/var/task/anyio/to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread( File "/var/task/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread return await future File "/var/task/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 807, in run result = context.run(func, *args) File "/var/task/routes/users.py", line 28, in login if user and verify_password(form_data.password, user.password): File "/var/task/crud.py", line 15, in verify_password return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password) File "/var/task/passlib/context.py", line 2347, in verify return record.verify(secret, hash, **kwds) File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 792, in verify return consteq(self._calc_checksum(secret), chk) File "/var/task/passlib/handlers/bcrypt.py", line 591, in _calc_checksum self._stub_requires_backend() File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2254, in _stub_requires_backend cls.set_backend() File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2156, in set_backend return owner.set_backend(name, dryrun=dryrun) File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2176, in set_backend raise default_error passlib.exc.MissingBackendError: bcrypt: no backends available -- recommend you install one (e.g. 'pip install bcrypt')
```

Comment: Can you explain "not working" in terms of *specific* error messages?

Comment: @tadman simply in local API is giving successful response( {"access_token": signJWT(user), "token_type": "Bearer"}) but globally it's showing unauthorized.

Comment: @tadman If removing the try-except block results in an internal server error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.